# PostgreSQL Nested JSON Querying

Tags: json, postgresql, psql, postgresql-9.3

On PostgreSQL 9.3.4, I have a JSON type column called "person" and the data stored in it is in the format `{dogs: [{breed: <>, name: <>}, {breed: <>, name: <>}]}`.  I want to retrieve the breed of dog at index 0.  Here are the two queries I ran:

**Doesn't work**

```
db=> select person->'dogs'->>0->'breed' from people where id = 77;
ERROR:  operator does not exist: text -> unknown
LINE 1: select person->'dogs'->>0->'bree...
                                 ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

**Works**

```
select (person->'dogs'->>0)::json->'breed' from es_config_app_solutiondraft where id = 77;
 ?column?
-----------
 "westie"
(1 row)
```

Why is the type casting necessary?  Isn't it inefficient?  Am I doing something wrong or is this necessary for postgres JSON support?

Answer (score 195, accepted):

This is because operator `->>` gets JSON array element as text. You need a cast to convert its result back to JSON.

You can eliminate this redundant cast by using operator `->`:

```
select person->'dogs'->0->'breed' from people where id = 77;
```

Comment: Don't forget to review the full list of JSON operators supported by PG https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html

Comment: what if you needed a list of all the breeds? is there support for something like `select person->'dogs'->*->'breed'`

Comment: @mga, see [json_array_elements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) function.
`select dog->'breed' from people p, json_array_elements(p->'dogs') dog`