# Select rows with value > x inside nested json array

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I would like to be able to select the rows where "likes" is greater than 50.

```
 {
  "id":2,
  "name":"TEST",
  "locations":[
    {
      "cityName":"NEW YORK",
      "lat":123, "lon":456,
      "likes":1000,
      "dislikes":5
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24944347/postgresql-nested-json-querying?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: So do you have your answer?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT( jsoncolumn, 'likes' )::INTEGER > 50;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming data type `json` and that your array always has just the **one element** like demonstrated:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  (js_column #>> '{locations,0,likes}')::int > 50;
```

Using the json / jsonb [`#>>` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-OP-TABLE) that takes a text array as *path*. Array index starts with **0** in a JSON array (as opposed to Postgres array counting from **1**).

If the array can have **multiple elements** (which is the point of having a *array* in the first place) and you want any row where at least one element record qualifies, things get more sophisticated:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl t
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM json_array_elements(t.js_column->'locations') elem
   WHERE  (elem->>'likes')::int > 50
   );
```

Related, with explanation:

- [Search a JSON array for an object containing a value matching a pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49824466/search-a-json-array-for-an-object-containing-a-value-matching-a-pattern/49826693#49826693)
- [Search for nested values in jsonb array with greater operator](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/202739/search-for-nested-values-in-jsonb-array-with-greater-operator/202761#202761)